# Reaction of NaOH with methanol and ethanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Methanol ($\ce{CH3OH}$) and ethanol ($\ce{CH3CH2OH}$) react with sodium metal ($\ce{Na}$) to form sodium methoxide ($\ce{CH3O^-Na+}$) and sodium ethoxide ($\ce{CH3CH2O^-Na+}$):

$$\ce{2CH3OH + 2Na -> 2CH3O^-Na+ + H2}$$
$$\ce{2CH3CH2OH + 2Na -> 2CH3CH2O^-Na+ + H2}$$

Do methanol and ethanol react with sodium hydroxide ($\ce{NaOH}$) in the same way as sodium do to form sodium methoxide and sodium ethoxide respectively?

Comment: They react, but not "in the same way". The reaction with sodium is a redox reaction (note the changing oxidation state of hydrogen from +1 to 0), whereas that with NaOH is merely acid-base. As for the reaction with NaOH, it will certainly proceed, but in general will probably not go to completion (see also vapid's comment on the answer).

Comment: @orthocresol If an electrophile (like CS2) is added to  the solution of Methanol in NaOH, do sodium methoxide will attack to CS2 to form sodium salt of xanthate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proposed reaction:

$$\ce{CH3OH(l) + NaOH(s) <<=> CH3O^-Na+(s) + H2O(l)}$$

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_methoxide):

> The solid hydrolyzes in water to give methanol and sodium hydroxide

The equilibrium is biased to the left, as @vapid has mentioned in the comments. To quote him:

> In the large excess of alcohol, the reaction will be considerably shifted towards alkoxide.

Comment: This answer would benefit from quoting $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values and how they influence the equilibrium.

Comment: Please do not encourage OP's abuse of notation which suggests a covalent bond between O and Na, it should be a superscript minus to represent the negative charge in the O atom.

Answer (score 3):

The reaction of methanol and ethanol are based on their $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values in the reaction.
Fist consider the reaction of methanol with water along with their $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values.
$$\underset{\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=15.5}{\ce{CH_3OH}} + \ce{NaOH}\xrightarrow{\enspace}\ce{CH_3O^{-}Na^{+}}+\underset{\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=15.74}{\ce{H_2O}}$$
Now you can see that $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value of water is a bit higher than that of methanol so the water will react with $\ce{NaOH}$ (*keep in mind that the reactions are in equilibrium, and for methanol it will be shifted forwards*).

Now considering the case for ethanol:
$$\underset{\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=16}{\ce{C_2H_5OH}} + \ce{NaOH}\xrightarrow{\enspace}\ce{C_2H_5O^{-}Na^{+}} + \underset{\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=15.74}{\ce{H_2O}}$$
Here it is clear from the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values that water is more acidic then ethanol and hence ethanol does not react to form water. It is not just the case with ethanol, rather all alkyl alcohols $(\ce{RCH_2OH})$ except for methanol does not reat with $\ce{NaOH}$.

If you come across a question asking that which of the given compounds dissolves in $\ce{NaOH}$, and if methanol $(\ce{CH_3OH})$ is one of the options then yes it will be your answer.

Comment: A lengthy and detailed account of the pKa of water recommends pKa = 14, and declares 15.7 to be erroneously derived. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Fundamentals/What_is_the_pKa_of_water%3F  The answer is currently correct in words, but the correct numbers will make it dramatically clear.

Comment: 'Than' not 'Then'